# When referring to a previously sent text, would you say 'I text you about that' or 'I texted you about that'?

Tags: technical

I realize *texted* is not a word, but *text* doesn't seem appropriate in the above sentence. What would make more sense?

Answer (score 7):

If *text* is used as a verb, which it is, then its past tense and past participle are *texted*.  As in

- I texted you yesterday
- I have texted you earlier today
- I am texting you right now
- I will text you tomorrow

Comment: I agree and thought this seemed obvious. I received a text that didn't use the past tense and realized I often get these. It was irksome to me so I decided to ask the question to see what types of responses I would solicit. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I think "texted" is a perfectly acceptable, if informal word. I regularly say that I "grepped" something (from 'global regular expression'). It's a neologism - a newly emerging word.

If the informality bothers you, I would say that the more formal version would "text-messaged".

Comment: The more formal version would be "sent a text message", wouldn't it?

Comment: That's the active form - mine is the passive. Both are good.

Comment: I’d agree that both versions are good, but it’s not an active/passive distinction — both examples are active.  A passive example would be something like “Hang on, I just got text-messaged by my sister.”  (For more details on reliably identifying the passive than you probably ever want to know, see Geoff Pullum’s [recent Language Log article](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=2922)…)

Comment: I would have given you a +1 for the first part of your answer, but the last part where you say it is an alternative to use "text-messaged" is a reason to give -1, so I end up not voting on this. "To text" is a quite new use, which is a short form of "To send someone a text message". "To text-message" is not something that is used. The more formal version would rather be as @Rahul Narain said in his comment.

Comment: Nothing informal about it. It's listed in both the OED and M-W with past tense of texted.

Comment: @Anwulf - good to know...then it's no longer even a neologism.

Answer (score 2):

*text*, in that sense as a verb, was not a word until they adopted it for the new technology.

Personally I adopted *texted* at the same time for past tense usage.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that *texted* is not a "word".  But as far as words go, I would personally use texted.  It does sound awkward, however the official past tense of *to text* is *texted*.

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/text

> He texted a long wish list to his parents two days before his eighteenth birthday.

Answer (score 0):

*Texted* is a word and is the past tense. See the byspels at both [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/text%5B2%5D):
*I **texted** her a little while ago.*
*I **texted** a message to her.*
*She just **texted** me back.*

and the [ODO](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/text):
send (someone) a text message:
*if she was {sic} going to go she would have **texted** us*

*If she were going to go ... (subjunctive)

Answer (score -6):

> I text her.

If a word can stand alone without adding -ed then the correct word to use would be "text". *I text her yesterday* stands alone without adding -ed.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand all of what you're saying, Linda white, but the broad implication of it seems to be that we would scarcely ever have occasion to use verbs with -ed endings. Please consider citing an authoritative reference work that supports the point you are trying to make here.